# ReactJS 'offset' property of 'stop' element does't apply value passed as parameter

Tags: css, reactjs

```
const StarIcon = ({ starNumber, stars }) => {
    const starOffsetCalc = () => {
        console.log(starNumber, stars);
        if (stars === 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (stars >= starNumber) {
            return 100;
        } else if (stars - starNumber > 1) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return Math.round((1 - (starNumber - stars)) * 100);
        }
    };
    const starOffsetValue = starOffsetCalc() + "%";
    return (
        <svg
            aria-hidden='true'
            focusable='false'
            data-prefix='fas'
            data-icon='star'
            className='star-svg'
            role='img'
            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
            viewBox='0 0 576 512'
        >
            <defs>
                <linearGradient id='lg'>
                    <stop offset='0' stop-opacity='1' stop-color='red' />
                    <stop offset={starOffsetValue} stop-color='red' />
                    <stop offset={starOffsetValue} stop-color='white' />
                    <stop offset='100%' stop-opacity='1' stop-color='white'></stop>
                </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <path
                fill='url(#lg)'
                d='M259.3 17.8L194 150.2 47.9 171.5c-26.2 3.8-36.7 36.1-17.7 54.6l105.7 103-25 145.5c-4.5 26.3 23.2 46 46.4 33.7L288 439.6l130.7 68.7c23.2 12.2 50.9-7.4 46.4-33.7l-25-145.5 105.7-103c19-18.5 8.5-50.8-17.7-54.6L382 150.2 316.7 17.8c-11.7-23.6-45.6-23.9-57.4 0z'
            ></path>
        </svg>
    );
};
```

The offset property passed as a parameter to the 'stop' element doesn't work.
Here I try to create a star SVG with a partially filled background based on rating.
When I use a simple string as an offset property it works ok.

Comment: So StarIcon, which is your variable, is equal to two parameters, starNumber and stars. The method to calculate the offset states: if stars is 0, return 0. If stars is greater than or equal to starNumber, return 100; else, if stars minus starNumber is greater than 1, return 0. Finally, round starNumber minus stars minus 1 and multiply by 100. Is this correct?

Comment: That is right. The problem is with 'starOffsetValue' variable

Answer (score 0):

I understood my problem. The cause was in ID's of the linear-gradient element. It should be unique if there is more than 1 StarIcon component.